# Lubuntu dual monitor doesn't save config

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, monitor

I'm using Lubuntu and I have a external monitor (connected using HDMI) to my laptop.
Everytime I enter on Lubuntu, both laptop and Monitor are turned on.

What I do: I go to Menu > Preferences > Monitor Settings and I disable the laptop monitor, I click on Apply and I do the same process again but I click on Save his time, just to be sure.

http://s7.postimg.org/s0fnce4cr/Display_Settings_001.jpg

I want to use ONLY the external monitor, I don't want to use the laptop's screen.

But this process is not working, because when I restart or turn the laptopn on again, both screens are turned on again ... seems that it's not saving my config.

Is there a way, maybe editing a file, to save this config? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves i3, it's not necessarily valid for other cases.

I've been using ARandR to manage my screens.
Though after the computer goes to sleep and I turn off the screens, it doesn't detect the dual screens anymore.

ARandR can save your config in a .sh file, by default in `~/.screenlayout/config.sh`

in my case with dual monitor, one vertical one horizontal, you get something like:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --primary --mode 1920x1200 --pos 3840x0 --rotate left --output DVI-I-1 --off --output HDMI-0 --off --output DP-0 --off --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-3 --off --output DP-4 --off --output DP-5 --off
```

In i3 config file (`~/.config/i3/config`) you can insert:

```
exec_always '.screenlayout/hv.sh'
```

This way, you just need to refresh i3 with mod+shift+R (by default) to update your xrandr config.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

In terminal :

Type `xrandr` -----> see what your laptop monitor is called ( maybe LVDS1 )

Now type `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off`

If its power on after reboot :

add : `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off`in `/etc/rc.local` and save .

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I don' know why but even adding this line to the file it is still not working ... the monitor configuration tool that Lubuntu uses here is lxrandr, not sure if it has its own options in terminal/file like the xrandr

Comment: try to replace xrandr to lxrandr in rc.local

Comment: Same thing ... maybe I'll try to look for another monitor tool and replace this lxrandr